# Identify the correct hashtag indexes in tweet messages

Tags: regex, go, substring

I need to identify the correct indexes in twitter messages (various languages, emojis, etc).

I can't find a solution that returns these positions as shown in the example below.

```
import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    text := " [URGENT] Les forces de dissuasion #nucleaire de la #Russie"

    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`#([_A-Za-z0-9]+)`)

    pos := re.FindAllStringIndex(text, -1)

    // FindAllStringIndex returns
    // [0][43,53]
    // [1][60,67]

    // These are the expected positions.

    require.Equal(t, pos[0][0], 37) 
    require.Equal(t, pos[0][1], 47)

    require.Equal(t, pos[1][0], 54)
    require.Equal(t, pos[1][1], 61)
}
```

Comment: You need to `import "unicode/utf8"` and use `utf8.RuneCountInString(text[:pos[0][0]])` and so on instead of `pos[0][0]`.

Comment: Please note that the flag you have has 8 bytes in UTF-8 encoding: `fmt.Println(len(""), []byte(""))` prints `8 [240 159 135 183 240 159 135 186]`. And `FindAllStringIndex()` returns **byte-indices**, not rune-indices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FindAllStringIndex()`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringIndex) function returns the position of bytes, not runes.

You need to `import "unicode/utf8"` and use `utf8.RuneCountInString(text[:pos[0][0]])` and so on instead of `pos[0][0]` to make sure you count the Unicode code points and not just bytes:

```golang
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"
    "unicode/utf8"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    text := " [URGENT] Les forces de dissuasion #nucleaire de la #Russie"

    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`#\w+`)

    pos := re.FindAllStringIndex(text, -1)

    require.Equal(t, utf8.RuneCountInString(text[:pos[0][0]]), 37)
    require.Equal(t, utf8.RuneCountInString(text[:pos[0][1]]), 47)
    require.Equal(t, utf8.RuneCountInString(text[:pos[1][0]]), 54)
    require.Equal(t, utf8.RuneCountInString(text[:pos[1][1]]), 61)

}
```

See the [Go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/WhBk6uYVd0M).

Also, `#\w+` is a a shorter pattern to match a `#` and then one or more letters, digits or underscores.